# Views removed using removeView() are there when I next open the Activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a MainPage activity that the user is taken to after logging in. This activity then dynamically draws one button on the screen for each subcategory it finds in my database in a TableLayout. This works, but if the user logs out and logs back in again then the MainPage will display twice the number of buttons (it never deletes the original set).

I have tried removing the buttons just before the user logs out using removeView(). However when the user presses log out the buttons disappear and the login activity is opened. When the user has logged back in the first set of buttons are still on the screen as well as the new set.

I'm an android newbie and I can't find anyone with a similar problem so I'm not sure if I've made quite a silly mistake here. It seems to me that I must be opening MainPage incorrectly, but I'm not sure.

Below is the code I think is relevant to this question.

LoginActivity, the lines I am using to open MainPageActivity if login successful:

```
    Intent mainPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class);
    mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    startActivity(mainPage);

    // Close Login Screen
    finish();
```

MainPageActivity, method that is called just before closing the activity when the user presses logout.

```
    public void removeSectionButtons(TableLayout tableLayout){
    int noOfRows = tableLayout.getChildCount();
    System.out.println("rows was "+noOfRows);

    for(int i = 0; i<noOfRows; i++){
        int id=i+1;
        TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(id);
        tableLayout.removeView(row);
    }

}
```

MainPageActivity, the case in onOptionsItemSelected() when log out is pressed.

```
        case R.id.action_logout:
        tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainPageTableTitle);
        removeSectionButtons(tableLayout);

        //code here to log out the user
        menuHelper.logoutUser(userFunctions, getApplicationContext());
        return true;
```

And finally the logoutUser() method in the MenuHelper class:

```
        public void logoutUser(UserFunctions userFunctions, Context context){
        userFunctions.logoutUser(context);
        Intent login = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
        context.startActivity(login);
        finish();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the buttons right before you add them? i.e call `removeSectionButtons` before you call `addSectionButtons`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately. I've found in the past that when I first open the activity and call getChildCount() on the table layout it says 0 (even if buttons are displayed on the screen from the last log in). Then I call drawButtons() and immediately after that call getChildCount() again and it has the right number of children (buttons in database + buttons that were drawn when the activity was previously opened). So removeSectionButtons() wont work because when it is called getChildCount() is returning 0. Do you have any idea why this happens? thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad, removeView() was working. The problem instead was with my database handling. Everytime the user logged out I was not wiping the SQLite database on the phone...but every time they logged in I was copying data off the server into the lite databse again.

This meant that when the user logged out and logged back in all the fields in the database had been duplicated so my code was displaying what was in the database as it should.