# getChildCount() returns 0 when called on TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This question is related to one I posted earlier. [Views removed using removeView() are there when I next open the Activity (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055707/views-removed-using-removeview-are-there-when-i-next-open-the-activity-androi?noredirect=1#comment40819352_26055707)

Background: When a user logs into my app they are taken from the login activity to the mainpage activity. The mainpage has a TableLayout that contains dynamically generated buttons. However if the user logs out and back in again, all of these buttons are repeated so I am trying to find out how best to remove these buttons after they are generated. In my previous post it was suggested I remove the buttons at the very start of the main page activity, before the new ones are drawn, so this is what I am trying to implement.

However when I call getChildCount() on this layout it does not always return the correct answer.

So far, here is the code that is run at the start of the main page activity:

```
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainPageTableTitle);
        //removeSectionButtons(tableLayout);  this is where i am trying to remove the buttons
        System.out.println("there are  oncreate " + tableLayout.getChildCount());
        drawButtons(tableLayout);
        System.out.println("there are  ondraw " + tableLayout.getChildCount());
```

The first print line returns 0 and the second print line always returns the correct answer (number of buttons drawn including all of the repeated ones). But I am not sure why getChildCount() returns the wrong answer the first time. If anyone can explain I would be incredibly grateful

My drawButtons() method is as follows (it draws two buttons per row):

```
     public void drawButtons(TableLayout tableLayout){
    //get the number of buttons
    int noOfButtons = mySectionTableHandler.getSectionDetails().size();
    //calculate the number of rows needed (there are 2 columns)
    //set flag to say if buttons are odd as it affects how many are drawn
    int noOfRows;
    boolean evenNoOfButtons;
    if(noOfButtons % 2 == 0){
        //even no of buttons
        noOfRows = noOfButtons/2;
        evenNoOfButtons = true;
    } else {
        //odd no of buttons
        noOfRows = (noOfButtons+1)/2;
        evenNoOfButtons = false;
    }   

    //counter to give each button a unique id
    int counter = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i<noOfRows;i++){
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

        Button a = new Button(MainPageActivity.this);
        a.setId(counter);
        sectionButtons.put(counter, a);
        counter++;
        newRow.addView(a);

        //if there are even buttons OR if there are an odd no
        //of buttons but this isn't the last row then add 
        //second button to row
        if(evenNoOfButtons || (!evenNoOfButtons && (noOfRows-1!=i))){
            Button b = new Button(MainPageActivity.this);
            b.setId(counter);
            sectionButtons.put(counter, b);
            counter++;
            newRow.addView(b);
        }       
        tableLayout.addView(newRow);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad, turns out I was re-adding data to the sqlite database each time the user logged in without wiping previous details.

So my code was generating a button for every field in the database as it should have been.